# How to do that content of button show in the left in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, button, controls

I have a button with width of phone width,I want that button content be image in the left corner and text after image, I put image and text into stackpanel, grid and canvas and gives HorizantalAllignment="Left"  but always the content shown in the center, how I can do what I want or which other control I can use,please help me

```
               <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="#FF479175">
                <Button Height="90" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="/HomePageDes;component/Images/main_news.png" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="News" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </Border>
```

Comment: Please add the XAML you use to the question. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: I've added a grid sample as well, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on your button`. The default is `centre`.

Then a grid with `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is what you are asking:

```
 <Button>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image src=""/>
        <TextBlock Text="ClickMe"/>
      </StackPaenl>
    </Botton>
```

If you are using Grid as your container, then you need to define Grid Columns and place the image in column 0 , and the text in column 1. Easier to use Stackpanel in this case.

For example:

```
  <Button>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
       <Grid. ColumnDefinitions >
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       </Grid. ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="/HomePageDes;component/Images/main_news.png" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="News"  Grid.Column="1"/>
     </Grid>
   </Button>
```

Comment: I can't without container, because otherwise it says that I set content twice, I used also stackpanel or canvas, but content always in center

Comment: @Vahan: My grid sample does use container. Its grid inside button.

Comment: @Vahan: just add column definitions to your grid and it will work.

Comment: it shows one after another, but again in center not in left side , if don't believe run on your comp

Comment: @Vahan: Add HorizontalAlignment="Left" to the grid. 
I can see you have solved it already?

Comment: MichaelS: however thanks, for trying help me, if my quiestion was usefull for you vote for him

Comment: @Vahan: I guess i didn't understand you correctly at first. I voted up.